# Jquery remove hidden

Tags: jquery

como podria borrar el hidden del div con jquery?

```
<div class="df-mobile" id="dffullscreen" data-layout="grid" data-facets="auto" data-browser-support="cssgrid voicesearch" hidden>
```

Gracias!

Comment: `$("#dffullscreen").prop('hidden', false);` o `$("#dffullscreen").removeAttr('hidden');`. Claro está que lo debe activar algún evento como hacer click en un botón o algo parecido... cuál es tu caso?. Por favor amplía un poco más la pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Dependiendo del evento que quieras utilizar en jQuery puedes utilizar lo siguiente para mostrar o ocultar un `<div>`:

```
$("#dffullscreen").show(); //Mostrar DIV
$("#dffullscreen").hide(); //Ocultar DIV
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!